# Inconsistent Compilation Between Windows and Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, g++

Context: I'm grader for a CS class trying to figure out why Windows and Linux compilers are inconsistent because people learning C++ can turn in some really weird things in their assignments. This isn't code that I'm writing, it's code that I'm figuring out how to grade (and prevent people from turning in!).

I'm trying to figure out why [the following code snippet](https://github.com/sxlijin/assorted-code-snippets/blob/master/language-semantic-examples/cpp/return_type_required.cpp) compiles on Linux but not on Windows:

```
$ cat return_type_required.cpp
// on Linux GCC complains
// on Windows neither MSYS nor MinGW complain, even with -Wall

foo() { return true; }

int main() {
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

On Linux (Arch) I get this:

```
$ g++-5 --version
g++-5 (GCC) 5.4.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ g++-5 return_type_required.cpp
return_type_required.cpp:4:5: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘foo’ with no type [-fpermissive]
 foo() { return true; }
     ^
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 6.2.1 20160830
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ g++ return_type_required.cpp
return_type_required.cpp:4:5: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘foo’ with no type [-fpermissive]
 foo() { return true; }
     ^
```

But on Windows GCC under MSYS2:

```
user@windows MSYS [...]
$ g++ return_type_required.cpp

user@windows MSYS [...]
$ g++ return_type_required.cpp -Wall
```

and under MinGW-w64

```
user@windows MINGW64 [...]
$ g++ return_type_required.cpp

user@windows MINGW64 [...]
$ g++ return_type_required.cpp -Wall
```

and insofar I've had no success finding anything in the GCC documentation or C++ standard about how this program is supposed to compile.

EDITS 1, 2, 3:

Still can't invoke a compiler error on Windows (I've also specified C++11, but it's the same for C++98 and C++1z):

```
user@windows MSYS [...]
$ g++ return_type_required.cpp -Werror -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors -std=c++11

user@windows MINGW64 [...]
$ g++ return_type_required.cpp -Werror -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors -std=c++11
```

Windows toolchain settings for MSYS2 as below:

```
user@windows MSYS [...]
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/5.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-msys
Configured with: /msys_scripts/gcc/src/gcc-5.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-msys --prefix=/usr --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --disable-multilib --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libcilkrts --enable-libgomp --enable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --enable-libssp --disable-win32-registry --disable-symvers --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --disable-isl-version-check --enable-checking=release --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.3.0 (GCC)
```

and for MINGW64:

```
user@windows MINGW64 [...]
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/5.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-msys
Configured with: /msys_scripts/gcc/src/gcc-5.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-msys --prefix=/usr --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --disable-multilib --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libcilkrts --enable-libgomp --enable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --enable-libssp --disable-win32-registry --disable-symvers --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --disable-isl-version-check --enable-checking=release --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.3.0 (GCC)
```

Comment: Regardless of which compiler "allows" it, a function must have a return type according to the standard. Therefore if the compiler allows you to do so, it is being non-compliant or providing an "extension".

Comment: It sounds like a GCC/MSYS2 defect.

Comment: Stop worrying about **why** compiler *xyz* compiles what isn't valid code. Instead, write valid code.

Comment: It has never been legal to omit function return type in C++. Yet it is well-known that GCC allowed it as an extension. But the fact that `-Wall` produces no diagnostics at all indicates a serious compiler defect. However, `-Wall` has always been pretty useless. Get a habit of using `-pedantic` or `-pedantic-errors` with GCC.

Comment: @AnT: According to the [warning options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.7/gcc/Warning-Options.html), a function without a return type should always produce a diagnostic for C++. The documentation isn't very clear, whether `-Wall` is required, but since the OP is passing `-Wall`, this is either a compiler bug, or something in their build environment overrides those settings.

Comment: @IInspectable: Is this also supposed to apply to the default language dialect used by GCC for `.cpp` code (which is formally not exacty "C++")? I wonder what the OP's compiler sould say if the OP added something like `-std=c++98` to the command line.

Comment: @IInspectable it's not that I'm writing invalid code. I'm a grader for a CS class and I (as well as the professors) are trying to standardize C++ coursework with GCC, and although this is code that shouldn't compile, I can't exactly penalize submissions for not compiling if they compile on the student's computer.

Comment: @AnT `g++ return_type_required.cpp -std=c++98` exhibits the same behavior on Linux and Windows.

Comment: @Pockets: Sure you can penalize for incorrect code even if it compiles on the student's computer.  For example, many cases of undefined behavior compile just fine.  However, it definitely would be a good idea to make sure the students have `ssh` login access to a Linux computer running the same compiler version you are, lest they send you *valid* code that breaks due to bugs in your compiler.

Comment: @BenVoigt we're rolling out Travis CI integration soon (which we can afford to do for the class I'm grading), but it's something we'd like to fix at the root, if at all possible, for the introductory C++ class.